# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I have system Ubuntu 18.04 where i have installed python 3.6.

I am running one script which has below lib

```
import mysql.connector
from google.cloud import storage
```

When i run the scrip i get errors as below

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

But i had installed those modules already not sure  what is wrong. Can anyone help?

```
root@sysadmin-ThinkPad-X250:# pip3.6 install mysql-connector-python
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.1.6)
```

root@sysadmin-ThinkPad-X250:# pip3.6 install mysql-connector-python
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.1.6)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import division
import time
import os
import datetime
import csv
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import mysql.connector
from os.path import join, getsize
from google.cloud import storage
```

Comment: How do you run your python script?  Do you just type `python myscript.py` at the command line?

Comment: I'm going to guess this is a Python2 vs Python3 dual install issue?

Comment: I'd guess it could be a `python -m some_dir.myscript` versus `python some_dir/myscript.py` thing, perhaps.

Comment: @JohnGordon  : I run the script as python3.6 script_name.py

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print(sys.path)`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be avoided using dependency management tools like pipenv or virtualenv. You will avoid a lot of potential headaches, especially on Linux/UNIX based systems.